# ViewState - proper way to store data in collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, viewstate

Assume I have a collection of objects

```
List<MyClass> collection = new List<MyClass>();
```

And a dictionary where these objects will be inserted

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>> sections = new Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>();
// example of insertion
sections["A"].Add(collection[2]);
```

List and dictionary are stored in a `ViewState`. Will it be more memory-friendly to store identifiers of objects in the dictionary and bind them with objects later, when I need them?

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> sections = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
// example of insertion
sections["A"].Add(collection[2].ID);
```

As I understand there will be no performance boost because in the first case dictionary will contain references which are 32/64 bits in size. Is it true?

**EDIT**

`MyClass` is a class, not a struct.
List and Dictionary are declared like this:

```
private List<MyClass> A
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["a"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["a"] = // retrieve data from db
        }
        return (List<MyClass>)ViewState["a"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["a"] = value;
    }
}

private Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>> B
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["b"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["b"] = new Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>();
        }
        return (Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>)ViewState["b"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["b"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, if `MyClass` is a `class`, not a `struct`

Comment: Where are you keeping your objects? They will be destroyed after your page has been sent to the client, so even though you are keeping references to them in your viewstate, they won't point to anything valid on your return trip.  So, you more than likely need to keep them in session, and once you have them in session, there really isn't a need to have anything in your viewstate to reference them.

Comment: I'm not convinced this will work at all, although I've not tried it. For this to work, you either need to have the entire object in your viewstate, or keep the objects in a state that can be referenced on a round trip to the server. If the object is kept in viewstate, that's a lot of information to be sent round trip to the client. If you are keeping the objects alive between trips, then you really don't need to have a reference in your viewstate, as it will already be in your session. In either case, I don't know if using viewstate at all makes sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it be more memory-friendly to store identifiers of objects in the
>   dictionary and bind them with objects later, when I need them?

If by "memory-friendly" you mean "smaller viewstate", and thus smaller page size, faster rendering, more efficient browser operations...

Yes, storing only the ID of a complex type will result in a ViewState string that is smaller than serializing the whole object graph. It's good that you are thinking about this and not blindly putting things into ViewState (a common mistake).

Couple things:

- ViewState isn't immune to tampering, so an attacker could attempt to submit IDs of objects to which they didn't have access. You can use [`EnableViewStateMac`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx) as a deterrent. I would still validate critical IDs manually to ensure that the user has access to them.
- If you use these objects frequently, you may be better storing them in `Session` or `Cache` rather than making numerous calls to the database.

Comment: Yes, I've meant exactly this. Thank you for detailed answer.